# Crear promesas con un array de datos

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promesas

Quiero usar `Promise.all` en una llamada a un `Webservice` pero estoy haciendo algo mal

Quiero enviar cajas de zanahorias a un servidor, cada caja estará compuesta por un `JSON` con datos como el peso, el tamaño, la cantidad de zanahorias...

Por un lado tengo el método que llama al webservice que recibe datos en Json

```
function enviarCajaZanahoriasAServer(cajaZanahoriaJson) {


    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {


        var options = {
            type: 'POST',
            url: URL,
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJson),
            contentType: "application/json;",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": TOKEN
            },

            success: function (respuesta) {
                    resolve(respuesta);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    reject(respuestaError);

            }
        }

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            console.log(" DONE");

        });

    });
```

Por otro lado tengo un array de cajas de zanahorias que contiene los datos de cada una de las cajas, este array se crea de forma dinánica y puede tener 2 cajas o 2000

> var listaDeCajasDeZanahorias = [];

Ahora quiero mandar las cajas de Zanahorias del array al método usando Promise.all

En los ejemplo veo que hacen :

```
Promise.all([function(datos), function(datos)];
```

Pero como aplico yo esto a mi código?

Lo que quiero hacer es esto, pero no sé como

```
    Promise.all([enviarCajaZanahoriasAServer (listaDeCajasDeZanahorias [1]),enviarCajaZanahoriasAServer
 (listaDeCajasDeZanahorias [2])..........]; //asi hasta todas las posiciones del array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) del *Array prototype*.

```
const promises = listaDeCajasDeZanahorias.map(caja => {
    enviarCajaZanahoriasAServer(caja st); // Devuelve una Promise
});

// Promises será un array de Promises. Una promise por elemento de la lista original.
Promise.all(promises)
       .then(r => {
           // Se completan todas las llamadas.
       });
```

La llamada a `map` la he puesto así para que se entienda mejor, pero puede ser más abreviada.

```
const promises = listaDeCajasDeZanahorias.map(enviarCajaZanahoriasAServer);
// ...
```

Porque `enviarCajaZanahoriasAServer` ya es una función que toma por parámetro una caja de zanahoria y **devuelve una `Promise` con la llamada al servidor**. A propósito, `enviarCajaZanahoriasAServer` debería devolver esa `Promise`, sino no podrás esperar a que termine.

```
function enviarCajaZanahoriasAServer(cajaZanahoriaJson) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var options = {
            // ...
        }

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            // ...
        });
    });
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: mucho, me ha servido de mucho. Mil gracias!

Comment: Una duda 
.then(r => {
           // Se completan todas las llamadas console.log("fin de llamadas".}); 

por la consola me aparece "fin de llamadas" pero en realidad no ha terminado con todas las promesas  . He cambiado el return new Promise  . Se te ocurre el motivo?

Comment: [Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/3matyozr/) tienes un pequeño ejemplo. Ten en cuenta que si una sola `Promise` falla, el `Promise.all` también se resuelve. En [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all) está todo explicado.